# Is there any way to determine current action (create or edit) in Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin::configureFormFields()?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'd like to create different fields configuration for create and edit actions in Sonata Admin Bundle.

Is there any way to determine it except checking `$this->getSubject()->getId()` in `Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin::configureFormFields()`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
  if ($this->isCurrentRoute('create')) {
    // CREATE
  }
  else {
    // EDIT
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

with:

```
if($this->getRequest()->get($this->getIdParameter()) == null){
   // create
} else {
   // edit
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as for me it's the same dirty hack as checking ID field of the entity object :)

Comment: This one does always return 'create' when the admin is loaded via sonata_type_collection

Answer (score 1):

I use this :

```
$creationMode = ($this->id($this->getSubject()))?(false):(true);
if ($creationMode){
 //Ok
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In sonata admin from version 3.x

```
  if ($this->isCurrentRoute('create')) {
    // CREATE
  }
  else {
    // EDIT
  }
```

In sonata admin before version 3.x use:

```
  $subject = $this->getSubject();
  if ($subject->isNew()) { 
    // CREATE
  }
  else {
    // EDIT
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
  if ($this->isCurrentRoute('create')) {
    // CREATE
  }
  else {
    // EDIT
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getAction(): ?string
{
    if (! $this->getRequest()) {
        return null;
    }
    $pathArray = \explode('/', $this->request->getPathInfo());

    return \end($pathArray);
}
```