# Form Type Checkbox Checked for create form SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm struggling with this problem and can't find the solution. I just moved to SonataAdminBundle today.

I want to make default value as checked for checkbox type but just in form create SonataAdminBundle. In normal Controller, I can define create and edit function with different form value. But in SonataAdminBundle the create and edit form seems just in 1 function :

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
             ->add('aktif', 'checkbox', array('required' => false))
        ;
    }
```

I've try add `'attr' => array('checked' => 'checked')` but that also happens when editing data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function getSubject() in the Admin class to see if you are in the create or edit form.

Something like this:

```
if (!$this->getSubject()->getId()) {
    // this is the create form
    $attrs = array('checked' => 'checked');
}
else {
    // this is the edit form
    $attrs = array();
}
```

and you write in options:

```
'attr' => $attrs
```

Good luck!

Comment: I'm sorry, but where I can get the documentation about this?

Comment: I don't find formal documentation about this on sonata site, but there are several questions on stackoverflow about this. One of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834765/is-there-any-way-to-determine-current-action-create-or-edit-in-sonata-adminbun . You can see the content of the Sonata class Admin for more information.

Comment: And next time when you create a new question, please search the issue before. As I said, there are more than one questions about this feature. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you always have this problem, here's a possible solution :

In your entity class, in the __construct method, insert this code :

```
$this->aktif = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are correct, but the best practice is to overwrite `getNewInstance` in your admin class like this:

```
public function getNewInstance()
{
    $instance = parent::getNewInstance();
    $instance->setAktif(true);

    return $instance;
}
```